# Table output not showing in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to show the information of the employee (that's logged) from database in my viewPersonalData.jsp file, but it just shows the table and not the data. The data is stored, because I can see it in my other jsp created to see all the employees that are stored (I can see them logged as an administrator), but right now I want to see only my data (logged as an employee).
I tried to find something that could help me, but i didnt find anything relevant.
Any help would be appreciated :)

viewPersonalData.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<t:pageTemplate pageTitle="View Personal Data" userType="Employee">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="dropdown float-right position-relative">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle h4 text-muted" data-toggle="dropdown"
                           aria-expanded="false">
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-centered table-hover table-xl mb-0" id="recent-orders">
                            <tbody>
                                <c:set var="userDetails" value='${requestScope.get("loggedInUser")}'/>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">First name</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.firstName}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Last name</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.lastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">User type</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.userType}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Gender</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.userGender}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Date of birth</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.birthDate}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Address</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.userAddress}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Religion</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.userReligion}</td>
                            </tr>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvHpE.png)
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Work program</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.workTime}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Salary</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.baseSalary}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-1">Bank account</th>
                                <td class="text-truncate">${userDetails.bankAccount}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</t:pageTemplate>
```

ViewPersonalData.java:

```
package com.ulbs.employeeadministration.servlets.employee;
import com.ulbs.employeeadministration.dto.UserDetailsDTO;
import com.ulbs.employeeadministration.dto.converters.UserDetailsConverter;
import com.ulbs.employeeadministration.entities.UserDetailsEntity;
import com.ulbs.employeeadministration.entities.UserEntity;
import com.ulbs.employeeadministration.managers.UserDetailsManager;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@WebServlet(name = "View Personal Data", value = "/ViewPersonalData")
public class ViewPersonalData extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get the currently logged-in user
        UserEntity loggedInUser = (UserEntity) servletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("loggedInUser");

        if (loggedInUser != null) {
            // Fetch UserDetailsEntity for the logged-in user
            UserDetailsEntity userDetails = userDetailsManager.findUserDetailsByUser(loggedInUser);

            if (userDetails != null) {
                // Convert UserDetailsEntity to UserDetailsDTO
                UserDetailsDTO userDetailsDTO = new UserDetailsConverter().convertToDTO(userDetails);

                // Set userDetailsDTO as a request attribute
                servletRequest.setAttribute("userDetails", userDetailsDTO);
            }
        }

        // Forward the request to the JSP
        servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/employee/viewPersonalData.jsp")
                .forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

[Here is the jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWTF9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting key as "userDetails" and value as userDetailsDTO in Servlet so in JSP you need to use

```
 <c:set var="userDetailsJsp" value="${userDetails}"/>
```

and then use "userDetailsJsp.firstname" .. etc for displaying values in table

Comment: I tried your version & it still doesnt work. I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: can you upload the project on github ?

Comment: I found out why it doesn't work. I had a problem with the authentification. I solved the problem there, and now viewPersonalData works. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate! it :)